# How to access user app data using php

Tags: php

Good day. Can anyone help me on how to access the user app data using a php code? Is there any built-in function for these? If you have any idea, please help. Badly needed.

heres a sample of the directory i want to access
C:\Documents and Settings\MyDocumentName\Application Data\

thanks in advance

Comment: funny, think about the security implications of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not (entirely) possible.

PHP code is interpreted on the server and the only thing that reaches the user's browser is the result of the PHP code.  You could build an app with a form that allows the user to upload the contents of their Application Data directory to the server, but I don't think that it will  turn out to be a very popular website.

Alternately, if you intend to interact with the user in a more intimate fashion, there are always avenues like Flash applications or (gasp!) ActiveX controls, but with browsers these days, most will flag your app as being a security breach and disable it.

Comment: actually its not really a web page. it is a stand alone program that uses a php script on it to access the database. It has to check on the user app folder of the user if the video is existing in the folder, if its not, the program has to disable some particular button related to the video.

Comment: In that case, I'm afraid that it doesn't sound like you're using the right tool for the job.

Comment: ahhh i guess your right... anyways,, thanks for clearing everything.